# configure: error: cannot find boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost

I am building dlvhex on Ubuntu 20 and I have boost version 1.71. When I execute

```
./configure --enable-python --with-boost=/usr/include/ CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include/boost"
```

I get the following error.

```
checking boost/iostreams/device/file_descriptor.hpp usability... yes
checking boost/iostreams/device/file_descriptor.hpp presence... yes
checking for boost/iostreams/device/file_descriptor.hpp... yes
checking for the Boost iostreams library... yes
checking boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp usability... no
checking boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp presence... yes
configure: WARNING: boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp: proceeding with the compiler's result
configure: WARNING:     ## ------------------------------------------------- ##
configure: WARNING:     ## Report this to dlvhex-devel@lists.sourceforge.net ##
configure: WARNING:     ## ------------------------------------------------- ##
checking for boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp... no
configure: error: cannot find boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp
```

I have this file on two different locations

```
/usr/include/boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp
/usr/include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp
/usr/include/boost/graph/distributed/adjacency_list.hpp
/usr/local/include/boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp
/usr/local/include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp
/usr/local/include/boost/graph/distributed/adjacency_list.hpp
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: try ```CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include"``` only if that will work

Comment: also did you install all of boost or you just nitpick some parts of it? you might need to put boost as is

Comment: Why not `sudo apt install libboost1.71-dev` ? https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libboost1.71-dev

Comment: Thankyou for the response. I have tried everything that you've proposed but nothing works for me and I am still getting the same error.